# How to solve this limit proof?

Tags: limits

I can't understand how to solve this, which is a part of a limit proof: 
$-\epsilon<-3x^2+3<\epsilon$
the result is extremely complicated because I analyzed one side of the inequality at the time and I can't unify the results because they seem to be incompatible. I think that isn't necessary adding my calculations, they are long, complicated and they probably don't make any sense... so, I hope in your kindness and knowledge to find out how to solve this mistery!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What is the question?* I don't see any limit here.

Comment: What limit are you trying to prove?

Comment: If the inequality is related to the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of some limit ($\lim_{x\to 1}3x^2$?) then you need not to solve the double inequalities completely.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is how to solve that inequality for $x$, here are the steps:

$$-\epsilon/3 < 1-x^2 < \epsilon /3$$

$$\iff -\epsilon/3 - 1< -x^2 < \epsilon /3 - 1$$

$$\iff 1 + \epsilon/3 > x^2 > 1 - \epsilon /3$$

$$\iff \sqrt{1 + \epsilon/3} > |x| > \sqrt{1 - \epsilon /3}$$

(Assuming $\epsilon \le 3$.)

Comment: why in the last line there's the absolute value of x and not x?

Comment: Because $x$ might be negative! So there is one more step to do if you want to write the solution just in terms of $x$, but I thought I'd leave *something* for you to do. You get two intervals, one with positive $x$ and another with the corresponding negative values of $x$.